# Remove saved git credentials

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm, clion, jetbrains-ide

When I try to clone a private repository using WebStorm/CLion/etc, it succeeds without prompting to enter any user credentials. Where are these credentials stored and how can I change or remove them?

---

Edit: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Answer (score 1):

If you clone over SSH then it's ssh-agent who manages the authentication.
If you clone over HTTPS then probably it is stored in native Keychain (if you are on Linux or MacOS) - you can check it in 
**Settings** > **Appearance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **Passwords**. And to remove credentials you can use Seahorse or GNOME Keyring or similar app.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution didn't work for me. The following one did work for me. please go to command prompt (windows) or prompt in other O/S

type this --

git config --system --unset credential.helper

it will clear out password stored in git and it will help you get you going..